# sub-Gaussian random variables in financial economics

Tags: statistics, probability, statistical-finance, normal-distribution, random-variables

Unlike financial time series that typically possess fat tails, sub-Gaussian random variables have strong decay in the tails of their distribution. do sub-Gaussian random variables or processes appear in any finance models, or are they useful in financial applications somehow?

[image]

Comment: I studied sub-Gaussian RVs at university (some time ago), but due to my lack of interest in them, I didn't learn the theory properly. One thing I do remember: tail convergence theory is not easy. I do recall that all the problem sets on sub-Gaussian RVs were an order of magnitude more difficult than any other topic on the course. I have never encountered the topic during my past 10 years in finance, so my personal conclusion is that the "value to effort" ratio for Sub-Gausian RVs (for finance) is too high. I look forward to what anyone else might have to say on this.

Comment: @JanStuller, I guess you meant *too low*.

Comment: @RichardHardy: yes, you're completely right, I meant to say that in my view, the "value to effort" ratio is too low (in my mind, I was imagining the "effort to value" ratio instead: funny how the mind works :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Since a uniform distribution is subgaussian, yes.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Perhaps because you do not explain how the uniform distribution is relevant in finance?